# batch expand nested variable without delayed expansion

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to expand a nested variable without delayed expansion?

Example:

```
for /L %%i in (0,1,5) do ( echo.%somevar[%%i]% )
```

Here a more detailed example of what I'm trying to do (I cant paste my whole code here)

```
::%1 list of keys
::%2 output variable
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
::parse some files and process information. Then it is stored into somevar
ENDLOCAL & (
    for /L %%i in (0,1,%somevar.count%) do (
        set "%2[%somevar[%%i].key%]=%somevar[%%i].value%"
    )
)
```

Comment: As has already been answered, yes, it's possible, however it's typically much slower and can result in problems with cointent that contains poison characters.  The question I would ask of you is why you don't want to use delayed expansion?

Comment: _If the variables are numeric_, then you may use this `set /A` trick: `for /L %%i in (0,1,5) do for /F %%a in ('set /A somevar[%%i]') do echo %%a`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few ideas for you, although I would recommend that you use delayed expansion, as in the third and fourth examples, and of those, advise that you use the fourth:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "somevar[0]=string zero"
Set "somevar[1]=string one"
Set "somevar[2]=string two"
Set "somevar[3]=string three"
Set "somevar[4]=string four"
Set "somevar[5]=string five"

Echo(
For /L %%G In (0,1,5) Do Call Echo(%%somevar[%%G]%%
Echo(
For /L %%G In (0,1,5) Do For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ('Echo(%%somevar[%%G]%%') Do Echo(%%H
Echo(
For /L %%G In (0,1,5) Do %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /D /C Echo(!somevar[%%G]!
Echo(
For /L %%G In (0,1,5) Do SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Echo(!somevar[%%G]!& EndLocal
Pause
```

Comment: In my scenario this is a helper script so it is called from a main batch, I use delayed expansion in the helper at the beginning but at the end (after endlocal) I need to expose some variables. How may this be achieved with your proposal?

Comment: How about you provide the context @lui, instead of expecting me to modify an answer to a specific submitted question, so that it instead matches another with zero information. If you edit your question, to include all of your code, from both batch files, _(without omitting any)_, and explain exactly the intent, then I'll consider adapting the above to suit.